# What does UpsertItemAsync do in the .NET Cosmos DB client?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

This question relates to `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.11.0`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.upsertitemasync?view=azure-dotnet) of `UpsertItemAsync` doesn't specify the exact semantics for the "upsert" operation. In particular, is it an insert + replace, or insert + (partial) update? (I suspect the former, given that [this issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document) is still open as of today.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CreateItemAsync` will create a new item but will fail if there already is an item with the same ID.

`ReplaceItemAsync` will replace an existing item with the same ID but will fail if that item doesn't exists.

`UpsertItemAsync` combines the above two operations so it will either create or replace any item with the specified ID. So it's not an "insert + replace". Instead it's an ["insert or replace"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-upsert-support-and-sdk-updates/).

Furthermore `PatchItemAsync` is now available so Cosmos also supports "partial updates".

Comment: Just to add a comment, the identity of a document is the ID + the Partition Key value (not just the ID).

Comment: how would you get the ID of the item. Does it mean we have to Get the item for its ID and then do an Upsert?

Comment: @saikumar: The three methods I have mentioned in my answer all operate on a single document. You have to provide the ID to identify the document to operate on (this is almost a pleonasm). If you have to perform a query (something like `select * from Container c where c.userName = 'saikumar'`) to get the ID, then yes, you will have to get the ID of the item by querying for the item.

Comment: Will the upsert also update the timestamp `_ts` of the document?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes, Cosmos DB automactially adds a timestamp field called `_ts` everytime a document is created or updated

Comment: PatchItemAsync (partial update) is supported now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.patchitemasync